# In eclipse how to create Override methods in super type?

Tags: eclipse, refactoring

When a class has `@Override` on its methods and those methods don't exist in the super type (interface), one can press `Ctrl + 1` and click on Create method in supertype.

I am dealing with over 50 such methods (which are not present in the interface). Is there a shortcut to create all methods in the supertype in one go?

Answer (score 0):

You can select one of those method , then click `Refactor` ➡️ `Pull Up` . The following dialog then appears. Then select the methods that you want to create in the super type.

[image]